# pass php variable to javascript function using ajax calls and getting response text on same page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function

I am using php sql database connectivity on a php page [search.php] for fetching data from a database in a variable "$url" and passing it to a javascript function where ajax calls catch that variable and passes it to another php page[function.php], This will execute some functions and send the response text back to search.php in a div whose id="rssoutput" see the code given below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>search</title>

 <script>
function showRSS(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML="";
return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {   
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","function.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script> 

</head>
<body>

<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
 {
 die("could not connect:".mysql_error());
 }
mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);
$query="SELECT * FROM table ";
$result=mysql_query($query);

while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$url = $runrows ['URL'];     

echo "<input type='button'   class='myButton'  onclick='showRSS($url);'     name='artbttn' >
<div class='container'  id='rssOutput' ></div>";     
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

So , What i am trying to achieve is getting data from another page[function.php] and displaying it on same page [search.php] in a div"rssOutput" when i click on a button . Can anyone tell me how is this possible.

Comment: And what isn't working for you ?

Comment: their is an echo statement in function.php that must be displayed in div id="rssOutput" in search.php @adeneo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use urlencode before sending it to the next page,

```
$url = urlencode($runrows ['URL']);
```

and then enclose $url with quotes like this: `onclick='showRSS(\"$url\");'`

```
echo "<input type='button' class='myButton' onclick='showRSS(\"$url\");' name='artbttn' >
<div class='container'  id='rssOutput' ></div>";
```

This should work.

**Edit:** rewrite mysql query with mysqli

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql="SELECT * FROM mytbl";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $url = urlencode($row['url']);
        echo "<input type='button' class='myButton' onclick='showRSS(\"$url\");' name='artbttn' ><div class='container' id='rssOutput'></div>";
        }
    } else {
      echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: not working  their is an echo statement in function.php that must be displayed  in div id="rssOutput" in search.php

Comment: it would be a dumb thing to ask, but did you refresh the page after code change? Also do you get any js error in browser's (or firebug's) console window?

Comment: I am not getting your point , why would i refresh the page ??

Comment: I mean when you changed the code, did you refresh the page to get new code changes on the current page?

Comment: no actually i am creating multiple buttons on multiple divs but url for every div is different everytime so when i click on that button a unique unique url must be sent to function.php and retieve back the response text in search.php but the problem is how to pass $url value to function.php using ajax calls

Comment: are you getting the expected url values in $url variable? and when you click the button does ajax call is made? or do you get any javascript error? (use firebug addon for firefox for debugging.)

Comment: no, no error nothing , their is no response may be its not calling the function.php

Comment: if there isn't any error, then check if you are getting any value in $url variable from mysql result. If it's blank your code will not send ajax request.

Comment: no its not blank i am also using it somewhere else for the link and its working properly but not working for ajax... i just need to pass this variable to function.php  and further functions will be executed automatically ... see this link i've tried this alse but i think i am doing it wrong so may you can understand this  ""http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/passing-php-variable-javascript-using-ajax-940450.html""

Comment: sorry that link is not working try this ::- http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/passing-php-variable-javascript-using-ajax-940450.html @Nikhil Supekar

Comment: I used your mysql query and didn't get proper result. So I tried it with [mysqli](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) and it worked. Anyway you should also avoid use of mysql_* functions as those are deprecated now, use mysqli instead.

Comment: did you get the results on div id rssOutput  @Nikhil Supekar , can you send me the code i really need that its important for me

Comment: actually i am also using $run = mysql_query($constructs);
    
$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);                                                                                                         while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))  and as i put mysqli instead of mysql  this show me error as   Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 167

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 169 @Nikhil Supekar

Comment: hey done but still not working even after applyig mysqli , I din,t used any depreciated version its fetching the data but still no response from function.php could you a bit more may be we can acheve it ..??

Comment: hmm.. this is very strange! well, add some alerts in `showRSS()` function. Check what value `str` is getting and let me know. Also which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I woner why i didn't get this before.There is a problem with url passing i think . What u need to do is to create a session as i have shown .

```
    while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $url = urlencode($runrows ['URL']);    
    $_SESSION['u']=$url;
    <input type='button' onclick='showRSS()' class='myButton' name='artbttn' >
    <div class='container'  id='rssOutput' ></div>
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>


<?php
echo<<<script;
<script>
  function showRSS() {

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {    
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
     document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
     }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","function.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
   } 
   </script> 
script;
?>
</html>
```

add the following lines to function.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['u']){
   $url=$_SESSION['u'];
}
?>
```

and use this url on your page.

Comment: thanx for your response mr. Detailer but still not getting the echo statement in rssoutput , May be its not going in function.php

Comment: i,ve tried to call this within php but the script under <?php
echo<<<script;  script;
?> is showing error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL in "

Comment: Hey @detailer  I've used alert messages alert('msg1'); in showrSS function its  going inside the showrss but not going in any of if else statements ...!!